# Rails 4 Replace words occurrences with form in post body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

I need replace each word between '--' and '--', every word can be extracted with something like:

```
labels = @post.body.scan(/--(.+?)--/).flatten
```

But, I do not know how to generate the form with which to replace the words (i think to use each word as a label). Something like this (but something that does work):

```
    <% if labels.length > 0 %>

    <strong> <%= 'Replace labels' %> </strong>

    <%= form_tag do %> 

      <% num = 0 %> 

      <%  labels.length.times do %>

      <p>
        <%= label_tag labels[num] %><br>
        <%= text_field_tag labels[num] %>
        <% num = num + 1 %>
      </p>

      <%end%>

      <p>
        <%= submit_tag ("Replace") %>
      </p>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

> @post.body = "--Lorem ipsum-- dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et --dolore-- magna
>   aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
>   laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. --Duis aute-- irure
>   dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
>   nulla pariatur."

labels [--Lorem ipsum--, --dolore--, --Duis aute--]

In this case the form contains three labels and text fields to enter the text to replace the labels.

Comment: Replace it with what?

Comment: Replace it with those entered via the form

Comment: Can you give an example of what `@post.body` contains?

Comment: Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited.

I think a simpler solution might be just using javascript to link a text field with inputs for each label:

```js
$(function(){
    var $label_holder = $('#post_labels'),
        $post_body = $('#post_body'),
        tag = /--(.+?)--/g,
        delimiter = /--/g;

    // When the label inputs change
    // Update the body
    $label_holder.on('change keyup', 'input', function(){
        var new_label = '--' + $(this).val() + '--';
        var text = $post_body.val();
        var old_label = text.match(tag)[$(this).index()];
        $post_body.val(text.replace(old_label, new_label));
    });

    // When the body changes
    // Update the label inputs
    $post_body.on('change, keyup', function(){
        var labels = $post_body.val().match(tag);
        labels = $.map(labels, function(str){ return str.replace(delimiter, '') });
        $label_holder.empty();
        // This creates an input for each label
        $(labels).each(function(i, val){
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.name = 'labels[' + i + ']';
            input.value = val;
            $label_holder.append(input);
        });
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="edit_post" id="edit_post_5" action="/posts/5" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_body">Body</label><br>
    <textarea name="post[body]" id="post_body" style="margin: 0px; height: 168px; width: 150px;">--Lorem asd-- dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
--asd-- magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
--Duis aute-- irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
    </textarea>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Labels</legend>
    <div class="field" id="post_labels"><input name="labels[0]"><input name="labels[1]"><input name="labels[2]"></div>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Post">
  </div>
</form>
```

Press the run snippet button and try it out.

The rails form would look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Labels</legend>
    <div class="field" id="post_labels">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Since we edit do all the label editing in javascript and send an updated `post[body]` we don't have to care about the labels in rails.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I will try with your suggestion, using a hash rather than an array seems the correct way. If you can be more explicit with the assembly or share a link i will be grateful!

Comment: My thought was that if you used an array and one of the labels was empty for example it would throw off the ordering. Not sure if that's actually an issue though. thats why the `hash.key?(i) ? hash[i] : str` part is there.

Comment: I am, unfortunately, too inexperienced to implement your answer, but thanks for answering!

Comment: I edited the question with a simpler solution. While writing I scaffolded up a Rails app which you can see here https://github.com/maxcal/sandbox/tree/replace-words-occurrences.

Comment: You are awesome! thank you very much for your patience and dedication.

Comment: I got the error `undefined method "labels" for #<Post:0xb5a8cb44>` which I have solved with an `attr_accessor`, but now i get `undefined method "each_with_index" for nil:NilClass`, any suggestions?

Comment: In this solution you don't need to split the body into labels on the server. Just add an empty `<div class="field" id="post_labels"></div>` in your form and get rid of `labels.each_with_index` ...

Comment: I understand, it's only javascript, client side process. I replace it, but the labels do not appear in the fieldset.

Comment: I edited the answer. For some reason `trigger('change')` did not cause the labels to be created initially.